# Running requests with different variables from a data set

Tags: postman

I have a request in postman that has:

- two separate variables in the link
- one Headers variable

I want to be able to export a csv file with 2 columns (variable 1, variable 2) and run the same request but with different variables sourced from csv file over and over until it's done.

Is it possible?

Comment: so, you have one request that gets the original csv, and then repeat with that data?

Comment: I have a request with X and Y and a csv file with 500x X and Y and wanted to perform the same request 500 times without having to manually swap these variables each time but rather have the Postman automatically change the variables for me.

Comment: Well, you can have it in your test runner, I think there is a good example for it [here](https://www.coolcodezone.com/api-testing/rest-api-testing-with-postman/postman-tests-with-data-providers-1/). it still needs some setup with a dataprovider, but it should match what you want to do with it :)

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for your answer but I'm not sure if that's what I need. I have a POST URL with 2 variables and all I want to do is have a way for these variables to automatically change based on my csv file. I'm really green here and only know basic stuff so I'm not sure if I'll be able to accomplish that.

Comment: I basically want Postman to Send my URL Request, change variables, Send again, change variables, Send again etc. until all variables from my csv are complete.

Comment: yeah, so that you could do over a collection runner, that gets fed with your csv file, which sounds to me exactly what you want :)

Comment: Yeah collection runner is what I thought would work for my issue but I have no clue how to use it. Will do some searching but if you have any tips i would really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

yes it is.

You can access the Data by {{ColumnName}} in your URI, Header, Body.

To access the data in test-code oder pre-request-script-code just use `data.ColumnName` or `data["Column Name"]` in case of blanks in Column names. In your case `data.sVenueId` and `data.shares`

You can use the Runner to import the CSV and run the requests for each row as an iteration.

The CSV file has to look like this:

```
sVenueId,shares
data1,data2
data3,data4
...
```

Comment: That sounds like what I need. Could you please help me with some tips on how to achieve that exactly? I'm really new to this.

I have a URL that looks like this:
https://api.xxx.com/xxx/assets/{{fsVenueId}}/sell/{{shares}}

and I need to feed the {{fsVenueId}} and {{shares}} data from csv. 

I added these to Pre-request Script

data.fsVenueId
data.shares

and in my headers I have Content-Type : application/json

and x-fs-token : token of the user I make changes to.

whats my next move here?

Comment: you need to add "fsVenueId" and "shares" as columns in your csv like 

```
fsVenueId,shares
1,2
X,y
```